# QuillJS Reproduce Slack-style editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm writing a messaging app similar, in some ways, to Slack and I'd like to reproduce a similar growing editor like they have with rich Markdown support, but I'm having trouble finding good examples of this. Can someone point me to some sample code that would help me how to do this with Quill?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [awesome Quill](https://github.com/quilljs/awesome-quill)? Specifically those -

- https://github.com/patleeman/quill-markdown-shortcuts
- https://github.com/morishjs/quill-markdown-toolbar

Comment: @double-beep I'd love to but I couldn't derive a use case from the question, merely a request for guidance and example code that deals with markdown and Quill.